# Characterization of $t$-gap prime pairs

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers

Everyone who dealt with the Pascal triangle knows the basic fact that *$p$ is a prime iff it divides each of the entries $\binom{p}s$, for $0\leq s\leq p$, except for $s=0$ and $s=p$.*

Based on empirical evidence, I propose a generalization. Throughout, assume $t\in\mathbb{N}$ is even.

> **Question.** Is this true? $p=t(k-1)+3$ and $q=tk+3$ are a $t$-gap prime pair if and only if
>
> - $p$ divides $\binom{k+1+(t-1)s}{ts+1}\frac{pq}{ts+3}$, for each $0\leq s\leq k$, except for exactly one $s$, AND also
> - $q$ divides $\binom{k+1+(t-1)s}{ts+1}\frac{pq}{ts+3}$, for each $0\leq s\leq k$, except for exactly one $s$.

*Caveat.* The exceptional $s$ for $p$ need not be the same as that of $q$. In fact, they always seem different and equal to either $s=k$ or $k-1$.

**Remark.** Even special cases, such as $t=2, 4, 8$, etc would be interesting to me.

**UPDATE.** I'm still waiting for some answers.

Comment: Do you also want t not to be a multiple of 3?  Or are composite pairs p q also of interest if they satisfy your conditions? Gerhard "Dotting Tees and Crossing Eyes" Paseman, 2017.03.15.